# How do I save multiple graphs from quartz in R using a loop?

Tags: r

I need to generate several image plots. I would like to have a loop or a function that will generate them and save each one to my working directory with a unique name. This is what I have come up with so far (with my still-pretty-new-to-R skills):

```
for (i in 1:5){
filename<-paste("array",i)
png("filename.png")
image(rawdata[,i])
dev.off()
}
```

This runs through the 5 image plots just fine, but they get saved over one another with just the name "filename". What is the best way to name each one differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving it the same filename each time (`'filename.png'`).

Use filename as an object, like `png(paste0(filename, '.png'))`

Answer (score 0):

Basically you don't need to store the filename, instead generate it on the fly via `sprintf`

```
for (i in 1:5){
   png(file = sprintf("filename_%s.png", i)
   image(rawdata[,i])
   dev.off()
}
```

Comment: It is arguable that the filename could be used in another place (for instance in a `main=filename` argument to `image` so `plot` adds a title to each graphic).

Comment: @OscardeLeón sure, but not in the example as provided.